# How do I add shaders to a renderer with multiple cameras in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, shader, renderer

I understand how to make an antialiasing shader with an FXAA pass, somewhat like so:

```
// scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
// camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 1, 100);
// renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(size, size);
// dpr
var dpr = 1;
if (window.devicePixelRatio !== undefined) {
    dpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
}
// passes
var renderScene = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);      // !!!
var effectFXAA = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.FXAAShader);
effectFXAA.uniforms['resolution'].value.set(1 / (size * dpr), 1 / (size * dpr));
effectFXAA.renderToScreen = true;
// composer
var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
composer.setSize(size * dpr, size * dpr);
composer.addPass(renderScene);
composer.addPass(effectFXAA);
```

And then rendering with:

```
composer.render();
```

I also understand how to display views from multiple cameras, as in [this example](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html):

```
renderer.setViewport( left, bottom, width, height );
renderer.setScissor( left, bottom, width, height );
renderer.enableScissorTest ( true );
renderer.setClearColor( view.background );

camera.aspect = width / height;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

But how do I do both simultaneously? At the `!!!` in the first block, a `RenderPass` is made using one scene and one camera. What I think I need is a pass that takes the multiple viewports and scissor stuff into account.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I isolated the problem in an example [here](https://github.com/asvarga/ManyRenderersWithEffects).

Answer (score 0):

have a look in this *example*... it will give you idea... **renderer** and **effectcomposser** with **multiple viewport**... http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_advanced

```
function render() {
var delta = 0.01;
var time = Date.now() * 0.0004;
renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, 2 * halfWidth, 2 * halfHeight );
renderer.clear();
composerScene.render( delta );

renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, halfWidth, halfHeight );
composer1.render( delta );

renderer.setViewport( halfWidth, 0, halfWidth, halfHeight );
composer2.render( delta );

renderer.setViewport( 0, halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight );
composer3.render( delta );

renderer.setViewport( halfWidth, halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight );
composer4.render( delta );
}
```